# How to Use Ai in 2D sprite Like Enemy follow player in 2D?

Tags: game-development, unreal-engine5, blueprint

So I am working on something and in my project square is my player and circle and triangle are enemies So How can I move my enemy towards the my player I tried lot of things but I failed… Please help me

https://i.stack.imgur.com/UbZJd.jpg

Give simple BP Solution

Comment: Do you need some code that just moves the enemies toward the player or you plan on adding obstacles in the future, meaning that you need a full-fledged pathfinder?

Comment: no just move the enemies toward the player not going to add any path

Comment: Then a simple "move to location" will be enough for you. This could be useful: https://docs.unrealengine.com/4.26/en-US/BlueprintAPI/AI/Navigation/MovetoLocation/